# CentOS 上での Guile のビルドで 型socklen_tについてのエラー

Tags: centos, gcc

CentOS 6.9（実機）で，guile-2.2.2 をビルドしようとした際，`./configure`
を実行すると

```
checking for socklen_t... no
checking for socklen_t equivalent... configure: error: Cannot find a type to use in place of socklen_t
```

との異常が表示されます。`config.log`には最終行に，

```
#define GNULIB_TEST_SOCKET 1

configure: exit 1
```

とあるだけで，異常の詳細や何をする必要があるのか分かりません。
`socklen_t`型については gcc 4.4.7 をパッケージとして導入しているのでライブラリに問題があるとも思えません。
解決方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

OS: CentOS 6.9 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc: gcc 4.4.7（現行; 実はこれを更新しようとする仮定でguileが必要になったんですけどね）
guile: 1.8.7（現行）

Comment: こちらの環境は CentOS 6.5 x86_64, gcc 4.4.7 ですが、config.log を見ると、`cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu11"` と出ています。また、guile の configure に、`Sadly, there is no released version of Autoconf with a nice C11-ensuring macro. This should work for gcc/clang within the last 5 years though.` と書かれています。 gcc 4.4.7 は `gnu11(GNU dialect of ISO C11)` には対応していないので、おそらく gcc 5.x 以降を使う必要がありそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえず外部でビルドした最新の gcc 7 を用いたところ，無事コンパイル出来ました。感謝します。こちらの configu.log に情報が一切表示されなかったのは謎のままですが……。

Answer (score 1):

コメントでのアドバイスを元に、外部でビルドした最新の gcc 7 を用いたところ無事コンパイル出来ました。
こちらの config.log に情報が一切表示されなかったのは謎のままですが。

---

*この投稿は [@cmplstofB さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34568/centos-%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae-guile-%e3%81%ae%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89%e3%81%a7-%e5%9e%8bsocklen-t%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc#comment34343_34568) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*